# scala code functional-programming facelift: extracting String from List[List[myClass.toString]] structure

Tags: scala, functional-programming, iteration

Please show me how to rewrite `toString` in a functional way.

The code is ok, but nothing to be proud of, there are 3 temporary variables in it.

```
class Field(x: Int, y: Int) {
  val value = init(x,y)
  private def init(x: Int, y: Int) = List.fill(x,y)(new Cell)
  override def toString(): String = {
    val temp = new StringBuilder
    for(i <- value) {
      for(j <- i) {
        temp.append(j.toString())
      }
      temp.append("\n")
    }
    temp.mkString
  }
}
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about this (*look ma! one line*):

```
override def toString() = value.map(_.mkString).mkString("\n")
```

Sometimes it frightens me how compact Scala code can be...

---

BTW if you don't need to reuse `init()` method you can simply say:

```
val value = List.fill(x,y)(new Cell)
```

Comment: Just what I was about to post.  Might not be as fast as the original, but it's way shorter and clearer.

Comment: Tomasz, yes, I used exactly your one-liner, but I could not rewrite it to handle the fact that the value that I need to concatenate is retrieved by calling the Cell.toString()

Comment: @NyitraiLőrinc: `List.mkString` implicitly calls `toString` of each element, can you show more code as it works fine for me with custom `Cell` class

Comment: omg, it works. now I will spend a few hours to understand exactly why. thanks :)

Comment: I was mislead by writing the Cell.toString after I tossed away the original one liner. I'm new to Scala (and probably to development), but this elegance is simply brilliant. Thx again.